# The general form of (algebraic) number field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials, rational-numbers

A **(algebraic) number field** is defined to be a finite-degree extension field of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Let $f$ be a monic, irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and $\alpha$ be an complex-but-not-rational root of $f$. It is known that $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ is a number field with extension degree of $\deg f$.

**My question** is that, for any number field $K$, if it's true that $K$ is isomorphic to some $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ as defined above.

Comment: Yes. This is a consequence of the theorem stating that a finitely generated algebraic extension of $\Bbb{Q}$ is [simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_extension). It holds for any [perfect field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_field) in place of $\Bbb{Q}$, but does not hold for fields like $\Bbb{F}_p(x)$.

Comment: See the [Primitive Element Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the question exactly as stated, the answer is **no**: $\mathbb{Q}$ is a finite-degree extension field of $\mathbb{Q}$, and thus an algebraic number field, but it cannot be written as a field extension $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ where $\alpha$ is irrational.

The answer becomes **yes** if you remove the clause "complex-but-not-rational". As noted in the comments, this is the content of the [primitive element theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem) when given the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is [perfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_field), a consequence of being characteristic zero.

Comment: (I am assuming that the question is about proving $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is a simple extension, rather than the simpler question about normalizing the representation to be defined by a monic integer polynomial)